# Map Australian cities - R spatial

Tags: r, maps, spatial, r-sp

I want to draw a map of Australia and represent each city as a dot.
Then highlight the cities with a high population (>1M)

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
data(canada.cities)
head(canada.cities)
```

I have checked the sp package where this can be done for Canada and some other countries. But Australia details are not there. Is there a special way to get the data for a country we like (name of cities, long, lat, pop)?

Comment: There's also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oz/oz.pdf

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but it doesn't have the cities or any population details

Comment: `world.cities[world.cities$country.etc == "Australia",]` and `map.cities(country = "Australia", minpop=1e6)`

Comment: Thank you. I got the necessary data using world.cities. Does map.cities() plot a map. I did following to mark the cities `Aus_cities= world.cities[world.cities$country.etc == "Australia",]` `class(Aus_cities)` `plot(Aus_cities[Aus_cities@data$pop>1000000,],pch=16,col="red",cex=3,add=TRUE)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now you have the data using `world.cities`, you can plot them a few ways

```
library(maps)
df <- world.cities[world.cities$country.etc == "Australia",]
```

Basic plot of points

```
plot(df[, c("long", "lat")])
```

on a `ggmap`

```
library(ggmap)

myMap <- get_map(location = "Australia", zoom = 4)

ggmap(myMap) +
geom_point(data = df[, c("long","lat", "pop")], aes(x=long, y = lat, colour = pop > 1000000))
```

[image]

On a `leaflet` map

```
library(leaflet)

## define a palette for hte colour
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd",
                    domain = df$pop)

leaflet(data = df) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lat = ~lat, lng = ~long, popup = ~name, 
                     color = ~pal(pop), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.6) %>%
    addLegend(position = "bottomleft", pal = pal, values = ~pop)
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this code, I get the yellow dots, grey area of the map  and legend (not demarcation or outline, no blue area, none of the names on the map) - Any idea why anyone?

Comment: I tried to post my picture regarding the comment above but someone called Samuel Liew thought it appropriate it remove my "answer" lol

Comment: @chris Your "answer" wasn't an answer, it was a question. This is why it was deleted. You need to ask a new question.